# Prove that $m∣n$ in m distinct fields among $\mathbb{Q}(\theta_1),\dots,\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n)$.

Tags: field-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ be an algebraic number field of degree n. Let $\theta_1=\theta,\dots,\theta_n$ be the conjugates of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose there are exactly m  distinct fields among $\mathbb{Q}(\theta_1),\dots,\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n)$. Prove that $m∣n$ and each field occurs $n/m$ times.

Let  $A=\theta_1, \theta_2 \dots,\theta_n$ be the conjugates of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let us consider the equivalence relation $\theta_i \sim \theta_j$ such as $\mathbb{Q}(\theta_i)=\mathbb{Q}(\theta_j)$ and let $\sigma_j$ be an monomorphism that sends $\theta \rightarrow \theta_j
$.

I have these hypotheses but I don't know how to proceed I wanted to know if someone can help me.

Comment: How much Galois theory is available to you to use?  Because it seems like the easiest way to handle this is to go up to a Galois extension of $k$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, iyou can use Galois theory.

Comment: What happens if you consider the splitting field $L$ of the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\Bbb Q$?  $K$ would correspond to a subgroup of the Galois group and the other fields would correspond to conjugates of that subgroup.

Comment: which is considered as L?

Comment: $L$ is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\Bbb Q$.  $K$ will always be a subfield of $L$, though not necessarily proper (if $m=n$).